# How do you stop linguini from changing file names?

Tags: linguini

When you use the linguini.File resource, it will automatically prepend the file names with the lot name and 'pilot' (when run in pilot mode).  Is there a way to overide (i.e. stop) this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

To stop the file resource from prepending the filename with the lot name, invoke it using the keyword `share=True`:

```
from linguini import File

File('/path/to/my', 'file.txt', share=True)
```

To stop the file resource from prepending the filename with 'pilot' (when run in pilot mode), invoke it with `ignore_pilot=True`.

```
File('/path/to/my', 'file.txt', ignore_pilot=True)
```

To stop it from making any changes at all to the file name, use the keyword `static=True`:

```
File('/path/to/my', 'file.txt', static=True)
```

Note that these settings don't change the value of `self.lot` or `self.pilot` within the resource---it only affects their inclusion in the file name.